# C# XNA Space Invaders. Tank bullet not showing

Tags: c#, xna

The bullets in my code seem to be shooting the invaders, since the invaders disappear. However there is no bullet coming out of the tank and hitting the invaders. I don't know where the bullet went.

Initialize Code for bullet:

```
recBullet = new Rectangle();
isRight = true;
isShotFired = false;
isBulletOut = false;
isBulletAlive = true;
```

Update Code:

```
 KeyboardState keys = Keyboard.GetState();
 if ((keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) == true || oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space) == false))
        {
            recBullet.X = recTank.X + recTank.Width / 2;
            recBullet.Y = screenHeight;
            isShotFired = true;
            isBulletAlive = true;
        }if (isShotFired)
        {
            recBullet.Y -= 10;
        }
        if (recBullet.Y <= 0)
        {
            isShotFired = false; 
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < numberOfXInvaders; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < numberofYInvaders; y++)
            {
                if (isBulletAlive)
                {
                    if (recBullet.Intersects(recInvader[x, y]))
                    {
                        if (!isInvaderDead[x, y])
                        {
                            isInvaderDead[x, y] = true;
                            isBulletAlive = false;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
oldState = keys;
```

Draw Code:

```
if (isBulletAlive)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texBullet, recBullet, Color.Green);
        }
```

I appreciate any help I can get for this! Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that you have correctly loaded your asset for your textBullet. Also can you show the method where you are calling the spriteBatch.Draw? (in case you are not calling it from the override Draw)

Comment: There is also the possibility that it is being drawn but the background(other stuff) is on top of your bullets so you can't notice it on the UI.

Comment: Another possibility is that the bullets are moving too fast to see. You could try lower values in your `recBullet.Y -= 10;` statement. If your update code is called every update they would be moving at 600px per second with vsync on, or much faster if it's off.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps:

1. First check if your bullet image is being loaded properly
2. Try to draw it on top of all your images. Put it on the last part of your Draw method.
3. If it is still not there, try to comment out all your spriteBatch.Draw and leave the draw for your bullet. If it's there, try to check your logic on your draw. Some images might be overlapping.
4. If steps 2 and 3 fails, repeat step 1